# test convergence: $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n $- sequence of all natural numbers which in notation doesn't use the digit 6

$\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$

I have already tried to compare $\sum(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{26}+...)\ge\sum \frac{1}{10n}\to \infty$ 
So this gives me nothing.

Comment: How many $k$-digit numbers are that that don't have a digit $6$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, you mean less and less. But whats about proof?

Comment: Quantify and get an upper bound for the sum of reciprocals of $k$-digit numbers without any $6$. Sum over $k$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583218/the-series-of-reciprocals-of-the-integers-that-do-not-contain-9-in-their-decimal

Comment: Just apply Cauchy's condensation test. How many "$6$-less" numbers are there in the interval $[10^k+1,10^{k+1}]$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yea it seems very similar, How did you find it?

Comment: It was sitting there on the side of the page, under "Related".